# Не работает HttpClient, ссылку собирает, но не передает

Tags: ssl, android, httpclient

Хочу, что бы он собирал и отправлял на сервер данные. Саму ссылку генерит, но никуда не отправляет. Не работает HttpClient.

public class LoginPage extends Activity {

```
public static String Login = "login";
public static String Password = "password";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.efrgtaw);

    final EditText account = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final EditText loginIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    // ProgressBar Progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
    final Button butlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    Login = loginIn.getText().toString();
    Password = password.getText().toString();

    butlogin.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Please wait, connecting to server.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            try {
                final String accountValue = URLEncoder.encode(account
                        .getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
                final String loginValue = URLEncoder.encode(loginIn
                        .getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
                String passwordStr = URLEncoder.encode(password.getText()
                        .toString(), "UTF-8");

                if ((Login != null && Login.equals(""))
                        || (Password != null && Password.equals(""))) {

                    butlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            try {
                                butlogin(Password);
                            } catch (IOException e) {

                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        public void butlogin(String password)
                                throws IOException {
                            // Create MD5 Hash
                            MessageDigest digest = null;
                            try {
                                digest = java.security.MessageDigest
                                        .getInstance("MD5");
                            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {

                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            digest.update(password.getBytes());
                            byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

                            StringBuffer MD5Hash = new StringBuffer();
                            for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {
                                String h = Integer
                                        .toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
                                while (h.length() < 2)
                                    h = "0" + h;
                                MD5Hash.append(h);
                            }

                            String URL = "https://"
                                    + accountValue
                                    + ".megaplan.ru/BumsCommonApiV01/User/authorize.api/"
                                    + loginValue + MD5Hash;
                            Log.i("httpget", URL);

                            try {
                                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                                client = this.sslClient(client);

                            } finally {
                            }
                        }

                        public HttpClient sslClient(HttpClient client) {
                            try {
                                X509TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {

                                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                                        return null;
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void checkClientTrusted(
                                            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain,
                                            String authType)
                                            throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void checkServerTrusted(
                                            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain,
                                            String authType)
                                            throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
                                    }
                                };
                                SSLContext ctx = SSLContext
                                        .getInstance("TLS");
                                ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[]{tm}, null);
                                MySSLSocketFactory ssf = new MySSLSocketFactory(ctx);
                                ssf.setHostnameVerifier(MySSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
                                ClientConnectionManager ccm = client
                                        .getConnectionManager();
                                return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, client
                                        .getParams());
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                return null;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }}});}}
```

P.S. Можно ли этот код как то упростить и оптимизировать?

Comment: Нельзя отправлять данные в основном потоке, используйте для этого AsyncTask.

[Отправка запроса на сервер][1]

[1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/134330/android-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try {
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client = this.sslClient(client);
} finally {
}
```

Тут только клиент создается, в отправки нет.
Для отправки используйте HttpPost или HttpGet(в зависимости от того, как на сайте)

т.е. создаете объект new HttpPost(url), Далее отправляете на сервер client.execute(post), и читаете результат.

Comment: Это без разницы http и https одинаково отправляются?

Comment: >http и https одинаково отправляются?
Это зависит от реализации http клиента. http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html вот у них даже статья есть.

Comment: Заработало! Спасибо!